# java regex - App name substitution

Tags: java, regex

I need help to fetch the related app-name from its job name.

```
Job Name                                     | App Name
---------------------------------------------  ----------
JOB:Level1_OSP_DEF_1_1443534637_3mqku88i_1_0   OSP_DEF_1
JOB:Level0_GRSPOL_1423634637_20afoikl_1_1      GRSPOL
JOB:Level1_DSP_113_%I_3qqkv2vk_1_1             DSP_113
JOB:Level0_BPKMG_12_1238534637_2a4foik1_1_0    BPKMG_12
```

I've tried some regex(s), but it doesn't generate proper results all the time.

```
JOB:*.*?_(.*?)_[*\d|%I]+_.*
JOB:*.*?_(.*?)_[t]*\d+?_.*
```

Rules:-

```
1. The App name can have a max. of 9 characters including "_" in middle.
2. The App name is present after the 1st "_" and always ends with "_".
3. The Alphabets in App Name will always be in CAPS.
```

Comment: What were you hoping to accomplish with `[*\d|%I]` and `[t]`?

Comment: Your rules do not sufficiently describe the APP-NAME.  In the first example line, you are trying to match OSP_DEF_1, however 'OSP', 'OSP_DEF', 'OSP_DEF_1' all meet the 3 criteria.

Comment: @Greg , just want to update the rules that need to be conformed.

Comment: @ajb , earlier the regex used to work, but with some changes in the environment, the regex is failing due to changes in name.

Comment: Well, those patterns in the regexes you tried look like things that would work only on some very specific examples.  So it shouldn't be surprising that they would stop working as soon as a few more examples came through.

Comment: @ajb, yes u r rite...the regex needs to work with very specific format of strings...the format that we want to maintain in job names... but as you know in environments, things keep changing... & we keep modifying the regex to match the changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming App Name should be the longest possible substring (unstated rule) that fits the 3 defined rules, and that *as a name* it is limited to uppercase letters (rule #3), digits (unstated rule), and the underscore (rule #1):

```
private static String getAppName(String jobName) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^[^_]*_([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})_").matcher(jobName);
    if (m.find())
        return m.group(1);
    return null;
}
```

Notice that this regex doesn't restrict the text before the first `_`, or the text following the `_` that terminates the App Name. This is fully compliant with the rules, which don't have any such restrictions.

*Test*

```
System.out.println(getAppName("JOB:Level1_OSP_DEF_1_1443534637_3mqku88i_1_0"));
System.out.println(getAppName("JOB:Level0_GRSPOL_1423634637_20afoikl_1_1"));
System.out.println(getAppName("JOB:Level1_DSP_113_%I_3qqkv2vk_1_1"));
System.out.println(getAppName("JOB:Level0_BPKMG_12_1238534637_2a4foik1_1_0"));
```

*Output*

```
OSP_DEF_1
GRSPOL
DSP_113
BPKMG_12
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer...This seems to be best answer in form of performance , flexibilty (& length of regex)..

Comment: I would have thought of something like this. One catch-up to keep in mind, though: if you have a non-compliant app. name (especially too long), the matcher will find nothing (e.g. `Level1_IAMATOOLONGAPPLICATIONNAME_something`). If required, it may be possible to tweak the regex to return something like `IAMATOOLO` in such cases. If this is not a case you may meet, this would be a useless complication, though, and this answer is already perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Such regexp works for all the examples:

```
"JOB:Level\\d+_([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})_(\\d+|%I)_\\w+_\\d+_\\d+"
```

Here's code which demonstrates it:

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static String extractJob(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("JOB:Level\\d+_([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})_(\\d+|%I)_\\w+_\\d+_\\d+");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (m.matches()) {
            return m.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(extractJob("JOB:Level1_OSP_DEF_1_1443534637_3mqku88i_1_0"));
        System.out.println(extractJob("JOB:Level0_GRSPOL_1423634637_20afoikl_1_1"));
        System.out.println(extractJob("JOB:Level1_DSP_113_%I_3qqkv2vk_1_1"));
        System.out.println(extractJob("JOB:Level0_BPKMG_12_1238534637_2a4foik1_1_0"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do your regexes obey the rule that the App name can have a maximum of 9 characters?  In any case, a regex that works on 4 examples is not a sufficient answer, because that doesn't prove that it works on all other examples.  And, unlike many posters who just ask us to write a regex that gets String Y out of String X, this poster actually gave us the rules he wants the regex to follow, although the rules are ambiguous and we need to work with him a bit more on it.

Comment: @ajb, 9 symbols limit added. OPs rules are very far from complete description of his problem, so it's impossible to "prove that it works on all other examples" as rules do not define strictly the set of all possible examples.

Comment: @TagirValeev , Thanks a lot for ur regex... I've modified it a bit and posted it { JOB.*\\d_([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})_(\\d+|%I)_.* }... if possible, could you check if there is a shorter way ?

Comment: @Marcos The first `.*` in that modified regex can match `_`, violating rule #2. Also notice that no rule specifies any restrictions on what's before the first `_`, other than the implicit "not an `_`" from the definition of "first". Both your regex and this answer puts extra restrictions there.

Comment: @Marcos, in general regexp should be efficient rather than short. Using `.*` in the middle may reduce the performance due to extensive backtracking. If in your case performance is not a big issue, then it's probably ok.

Comment: @TagirValeev, Thaks a lot for your advice.. I've changed it a bit again -- JOB:Level\d+_([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})_(\d+|%I)_.* ... This seems to be bit better in performance.... Also, you are right.. the regex with "JOB.*\d_" has failed in tests..miserably...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples I would assume the job is concatenated by six fields which are separated by an underscore. The idea to find the application name is to remove the first and the trailing four fields. Which would make the extraction rule simplier and more robust if the rule for application name is changed (different characters or length allowed).

One example to explain.

```
JOB:Level1_OSP_DEF_1_1443534637_3mqku88i_1_0
    +----+ +-------+ +--------+ +------+ + +
       |       |          |         |    | |
       |       |          |         |    | +- field 6
       |       |          |         |    +--- field 5
       |       |          |         +-------- field 4
       |       |          +------------------ field 3
       |       +----------------------------- field 2
       +------------------------------------- field 1
```

The code remvoves everthing till the first `_` inluding (`JOB:Level1_` is matched in the regex by `[^_]*_`) and the tail which starts with an `_` (the separtor between field 2 and 3) and contains three other `_` (the separator between fields 4, 5, 6). The tail is matchend in the regex by `(_.*){4}`. In the regex the `(.*)` matches averthing between the field 1 and field 4.

```
String[] jobs = { "JOB:Level1_OSP_DEF_1_1443534637_3mqku88i_1_0", 
    "JOB:Level0_GRSPOL_1423634637_20afoikl_1_1",
    "JOB:Level1_DSP_113_%I_3qqkv2vk_1_1",
    "JOB:Level0_BPKMG_12_1238534637_2a4foik1_1_0"};
for (String job : jobs) {
    System.out.printf("%-45s - %s%n", job, job.replaceAll("[^_]*_(.*)(_.*){4}", "$1"));
}
```

output

```
JOB:Level1_OSP_DEF_1_1443534637_3mqku88i_1_0  - OSP_DEF_1
JOB:Level0_GRSPOL_1423634637_20afoikl_1_1     - GRSPOL
JOB:Level1_DSP_113_%I_3qqkv2vk_1_1            - DSP_113
JOB:Level0_BPKMG_12_1238534637_2a4foik1_1_0   - BPKMG_12
```

Comment: It is not necessary that the strings will always have 6 "_", there can be 5 or 7 as well..

Comment: @Marcos This is covered by the example. `5` for `GRSPOL` and `7` for `OSP_DEF_1`. I assume the number of fields is always six and they are concatenated with by a `_`. So if you remove the first and last four fields, the remaining is the second field. Independent how many `_` you have in the second field. I update my anwer to make is more clear.