# Java regex for replacement with delimiter as : or $

Tags: java, regex

I've jobs running following non-standard naming conventions with some job examples below:

```
=========================================
Job Name                     | New Name
----------------------------- ----------
JOB:/Level0_APP1_12345_0/      JOB
JOB:Level1_DBASW_t323dk23_p1   JOB
JOB$SAV:                       JOB
backup:SYNC1                   backup
QUERY:logs                     QUERY
QUERY$maps:                    QUERY
QUERY:                         QUERY 
FS1:\                          FS1:\    -- No change in name
PS:\MXMI                       PS:\MXMI -- No change in name
========================================
```

The delimiter is either (;) or ($) whichever comes first. Also, the regex should not job which have (:\) in name, as shown in last 2 examples.

I've used the below, but without success

```
Regex:
(:|\$[a-zA-Z\/0-9]+)|(\$[a-zA-Z\/0-9]+)|(:$)
(.*)((\:|\$)([a-zA-Z\/0-9]+|$))
(.*)((\:|\$)(.*|$))

Substitution -> $1
```

Comment: Check [`(\w+)[:$][^\\]*?\s`](https://regex101.com/r/uO3vC1/1)

Comment: @Tushar, Could you post this as answer.

Comment: First I tought you might be a colleague of [him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665774/java-regex-app-name-substitution/33666257) who had a similar strange job name convention. But then I have seen the question was raised by yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple regex here:

```
^(.*?)(?::(?!\\)|\$).*
```

It [matches](https://regex101.com/r/nW6aN5/1):

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - capture into Group 1 as few symbols (other than a newline) as possible before the first...

  - `(?::(?!\\)|\$)` - either `:` that is not followed by `\` (with `(?::(?!\\)`) or a literal `$` (with `\$`)
- `.*` - match the rest of the *line*

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/xxHg7G):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("JOB:/Level0_APP1_12345_0/", "JOB:Level1_DBASW_t323dk23_p1",
      "JOB$SAV:", "backup:SYNC1","QUERY:logs","QUERY$maps:","QUERY:","FS1:\\","PS:\\MXMI");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^(.*?)(?::(?!\\\\)|\\$).*", "$1"));
```

Output:

```
JOB
JOB
JOB
backup
QUERY
QUERY
QUERY
FS1:\
PS:\MXMI
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(\w+(?=:\\.+):\\.+|[^:$]+)
```

The first capturing group ($1) is what you are looking for